# Unable to merge 2 tables

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables that are similar:

Table1 
    Artist         Title       ISRC    Album Title
    John Smith     Above All   12345
    Craig Smith    Above All   56789
    Lenny LeBlanc  Above All   98765

Table2 
    Artist         Title       ISRC    Album Title     Filename
    John Smith     Above All
    Craig Smith    Above All

This is not giving me the result I am looking for:

```
    SELECT table2.filename, 
           table2.artist, 
           table2.title, 
           table1.num, 
           table2.album_title, 
           table2.record_label 
      FROM table2 
INNER JOIN table1 ON table1.artist = table2.artist
```

Table1 has ISRC's that are not in Table2 although Table2 has some ISRC's found in Table1. I am needing to populate Table2 with the missing ISRC's.

As you can see either table can have different artists with the same Title. I am only looking for exact matches in Table2 that are missing ISRCs.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It is unclear what you want to do.

Comment: i think you should use table2 LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 , inner join gives only common values. if you give some more clarification than it is easy to solve.

Comment: I edited above and put some data in, but it did not come out as clean as I had hoped.

Answer (score 1):

First step in this case would be applying "RIGHT JOIN" instead of "INNER JOIN". In your query it will keep all records from table1, while joining records from table2 where possible.

However, if you need all IRCS found in both tables (and joined together where possible), FULL JOIN is a better option.

Answer (score 1):

i think you need left join

```
SELECT table2.filename, 
           table2.artist, 
           table2.title, 
           table1.num, 
           table2.album_title, 
           table2.record_label 
      FROM table2 
left JOIN table1 ON table1.artist = table2.artist
```